# position absolute responsive to position absolute's width auto

Tags: html, css, css-position

This is my CSS example: https://jsfiddle.net/80e4u0dd/
When You hover orange box, then the `a` element is underlined.
The orange box must be above the "long text" in green box, like it is now.

The problem is that the orange box isn't responsive to blue box. I gave to it `right: 106px` to show an example. **The orange box should always be over the green box and left to blue box**.

```
.green {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    background: green;
}

.green a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #212121;
}

.green a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.blue {
    position: absolute;
    float: right;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    background: blue;
}

.blue p {
    margin-right: 5px;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
}

.orange {
    position: absolute;
    float: right;
    right: 106px;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 45px;
    background: orange;
}



<div style="width: 400px; height: 100px;">
    <div class="green">
        <div class="blue">
            <p>SHORT TEXT</p>
        </div>
        <a href="#">
            LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG                     TEXT   LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT   LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT   LONG TEXT                   LONG TEXT LONG TEXT   LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT   LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG                   TEXT   LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT                            
            <span class="orange"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not clear what this is supposed to look like.

Comment: Blue div has width:auto; when the width of blue div is higher, then orange div should be still floated right to blue div.

Comment: Sorry...do you have an image of the desired result?

Comment: [**something like this?**](https://jsfiddle.net/hurrm336/)

Comment: I want to be orange div always at blue div no matter what width of blue div it is.

Comment: freestock.tk yes, but the orange div should be at left side of blue div. it is not at its right side. :)

Comment: on the question you said "The orange box should always be over the green box and right to blue box"

Comment: Sorry, left to blue box. I just thought about right side of orange div to left side of blue div.
// EDITED !!!

Comment: Should be similar to this: https://jsfiddle.net/d2gs7cju/

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding

```
z-index:auto;
```

and changing the width of orange div to higher. It is not responsive to blue, but it do the thing.